# Javascript Error $(...).dxChart is not a function

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, devexpress, devexpress-mvc, devextreme

I'm trying to display a dxChart with jQuery binding in an ASP.NET MVC project (with DevExpress). So I included the necessary scripts in the rootLayout:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/knockout-3.0.0.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/globalize.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/dx.chartjs.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Then I added the div tag and the binding script in a partial view:

```
<div id='chartContainer'></div>
<script>
    $(function() {
    var dataSource = @Html.Raw(Model.RepartitionDesRdvs);
        $("#chartContainer").dxChart({
            size: {
                width: 300
            },
            dataSource: dataSource,
            commonSeriesSettings: {
                argumentField: 'Statut',
                type: 'pie'
            },
            series: [
                {
                    argumentField: "Statut",
                    valueField: "Total",
                    label: {
                        visible: true,
                        connector: {
                            visible: true,
                            width: 1
                        }
                    }
                }
            ],
            title: "Répartition des Rendez Vous",
            onPointClick: function (e) {
                var point = e.target;
                point.isVisible() ? point.hide() : point.show();
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Nothing shows in the view and I get this error:

```
TypeError: $(...).dxChart is not a function
```

What am I missing ?

Comment: Does dx.chartjs.js exist in that location? If you check your browser's developer tools you will be able to see what scripts have been loaded

Comment: As per DevExpress Site's input - `To use DevExtreme data visualization widgets, reference the following libraries on your page. jQuery version 2.0.1+ (but 1.10.0+ for IE 8)`. http://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/Howto/Data_Visualization/Basics/Create_a_Widget/?version=14_2#Add_Libraries

Comment: Please get new version of JQuery and reference it. Let me know if my above comment helps you to resolve the issue.

Comment: @ramiramilu I added jquery-2.1.3 instaid of jquery-1.10.2 but the error is the same.

Comment: Looks like the chartjs library does not exist in your project. You can try to use CDN scripts https://cdn3.devexpress.com/jslib/14.2.6/js/dx.chartjs.js instead of local dx.chart.js file.

Comment: @Sergey I tried that it has the same effect. Actually when I inspect the page source and I got to the dx.chartjs.js file I can access it and see its content

Comment: Be sure you place your code after main libraries. First, you should append `jQuery`, `globalize`, `dx.chart.js` to a page. Next, add a code that initializes `dxChart()`.

Comment: I did (you can see that in the code in my question) placed the libs in my rootLayout in the order described here: http://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/Howto/Data_Visualization/Basics/Create_a_Widget/?version=14_2#Add_Libraries and when I initialize dxChart() I still get the same error

Comment: Try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your problem, perhaps as a jsfiddle or similar. This will make it a lot easier for someone to help you. As it is now it's only left for someone to make guesses.

Comment: I have used DevExtreme in an ASP.NET WebForms and I remember that I also used a js named dx.webapp.js (if I am not wrong). May you miss the second devextreme .js ?

Comment: @ManolisXountasis $(...).dxChart is not included in dx.webapp.js although I added its reference but it did no effect :/

Answer (score 3):

I encountered this issue also, using  Dx Version: 15.2.5 and JQuery 2.1.4 & 2.2.0.  The issue led me to this SO.  As has been suggested, I re-pointed my << script >> tags to the following CDN.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/globalize/0.1.1/globalize.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn3.devexpress.com/jslib/15.2.5/js/dx.chartjs.js"></script>
```

This did appear to work, so I manually downloaded the CDN files and used Beyond Compare to diff. Surprisingly, BC showed differences in jquery. After replacing the contents of my local files with the CDN versions, I tried again and found the error to be still present.

```
TypeError: $(...).dxChart is not a function
```

What solved it for me was to place the the chartjs after the DevExpress MVC scripts.

```
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/dx.common.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/dx.light.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.4.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/globalize.min.js")"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/angular.js")"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/angular-sanitize.js")"></script>
    @Html.DevExpress().GetStyleSheets(
...
    )
    @Html.DevExpress().GetScripts(
...
    )

    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/dx.chartjs.js")"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/custom.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: The thing is that `@Html.DevExpress().GetScripts(...)` generates a custom jquery for DevExpress extensions so putting `<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/dx.chartjs.js")"></script>` before the extensions helper overwrites it: here's a similar ticket:
https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T330073