# Unable to render DevExtreme pie chart in jsFiddle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, devextreme

In [my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xameeramir/51h3bmgf/), I'm trying to [replicate](http://jsfiddle.net/ChartJS/4ccgA/) plotting a [DevExpress's DevExtreme doughnut chart](http://js.devexpress.com/Demos/WidgetsGallery/#demo/charts-doughnut_series-doughnut):

```js
var dataSource = [{
  region: "Asia",
  val: 4119626293
}, {
  region: "Africa",
  val: 1012956064
}, {
  region: "Northern America",
  val: 344124520
}, {
  region: "Latin America and the Caribbean",
  val: 590946440
}, {
  region: "Europe",
  val: 727082222
}, {
  region: "Oceania",
  val: 35104756
}];

$("#container").dxPieChart({
  dataSource: dataSource,
  title: "The Population of Continents and Regions",
  tooltip: {
    enabled: true,
    format: "millions",
    percentPrecision: 2,
    customizeTooltip: function(arg) {
      return {
        text: arg.valueText + " - " + arg.percentText
      };
    }
  },
  legend: {
    horizontalAlignment: "right",
    verticalAlignment: "top",
    margin: 0
  },
  series: [{
    type: "doughnut",
    argumentField: "region",
    label: {
      visible: true,
      format: "millions",
      connector: {
        visible: true
      }
    }
  }]
});
```

```css
#container {
  height: 440px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

This [official code](http://js.devexpress.com/Demos/WidgetsGallery/#demo/charts-doughnut_series-doughnut) is working in [ChartJS's fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ChartJS/4ccgA/).

Since I'm not doing it in an ASP.NET MVC project, [`chartjs` after the DevExpress MVC scripts shall not be an issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35523879/2404470)

What am I missing here?

Comment: You have some errors. Check the console.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the console - it isn't finding the `.dxPieChart` function because it can't load the 'insecure' chart.js script:

'Mixed Content: The page at 'https://jsfiddle.net/xameeramir/51h3bmgf/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script 'http://cdn3.devexpress.com/jslib/15.2.10/js/dx.chartjs.js'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.'

Maybe you find a `https` CDN link for the library?

Comment: It does work, you just need to use a HTTPS CDN link for the external library. You may be hard pressed to find one though as the library you're using is not free.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan If I understand correctly, I've removed the `https` thing entirely by moving to [`http`](http://jsfiddle.net/xameeramir/51h3bmgf/). Still it's not rendering

Comment: No, the problem is that you're trying to load `http://cdn3.devexpress.com/jslib/15.2.10/js/dx.chartjs.js`, which is not a secure (`https`) link. You should try to find a link to the same library that IS `https`.

Comment: @otajor - Yes, `https` was the issue, so I'm using [plain http](http://jsfiddle.net/xameeramir/51h3bmgf/). Btw, I was able to solve the issue by [re-ordering the script files](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T109201)

Answer (score 1):

Change http cdn to https. Https cdn for the devextreme chartjs 13.1.5 library: https://dxjscdn2.blob.core.windows.net/jslib/13.1.5/js/dx.chartjs.js

Comment: Thanks for your inputs!